# Java regex question: How to match a sting exactly N-th field?

Tags: regex

I am trying to check 15th field (field delimited by |), and see if the value is `"RAV"`.
Sample line is here

```
'8/23/2022 7:35:08 AM|33224455|DF My-Store|ABCD-OY-MMNNYYDD|98121928|DF|FNU LNU|1234 ISLAND COVE CT|DELTA LAKE|CT|98765-8470||73023|MIS|MIS VAR DISPLAY|RAV||MYDF'
```

Regex formula I use is

```
(^([^|]*\|){15}\K[^|]*$)|(([RAV]){3})
```

It detects "RAV" in 17th field. But if the string "RAV" in second or 3rd or any other field before or after 15the field then also I get pattern match which is not I am expecting.  I need to match strictly 15th field, not before or after.

How do I do it? what mistake I am making here?  Please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: To check for at least 14 preceding fields and 'RAV' in the 15th, try: [`^(?:[^|]*\|){15}RAV(?:\|[^|]*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/UeDMSQ/1), unless what you are trying to avoid `RAV` anywhere other than 15th field too.

Comment: You mean if `RAV` comes before or after 15th field  then it should fail the match?

Comment: Why do you use a regex and not `String#split` and then access the 15th field with `[14]`?

Answer (score 0):

You may use this regex to match `RAV` only in `16th` field. It will fail the match if `RAV` appears in any other field before or after.

```bash
^(?:(?!RAV\|)[^|]*\|){15}\KRAV(?!.*\|RAV(?:\||$))(?=\||$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G5H3D2/1)

btw `\K` is not supported in Java, it is only supported in PCRE flavor.

If you want use this regex in Java then use a capture group:

```bash
^(?:(?!RAV\|)[^|]*\|){15}(RAV)(?!.*\|RAV(?:\||$))(?=\||$)
```

Comment: No.  Java expression returns entire string from 0 to 15th position in java.  Match 1: 0-155 '8/23/2022 7:35:08 AM|33224455|DF My-Store|ABCD-OY-MMNNYYDD|98121928|DF|FNU LNU|1234 ISLAND COVE CT|DELTA LAKE|CT|98765-8470||73023|MIS|MIS VAR DISPLAY|RAV

Comment: expecting just RAV in match 1, instead it returns entire string from the beginning until 15th field.  How do I reset from 152-155 in this string ?

Comment: As mentioned in answer, you cannot use `\K` in Java, just use capture group for your match (as shown in 2nd regex)

Comment: Anubhava - Second regex one, it returns match for any field, not just 15.  How do I limit the pattern to 15th field ?

Comment: Didn't understand your comment. Can you clarify with an example